# Android how to package a build?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, apk

I just realized that I have been developing android for months but I ALWAYS send my builds to a phone or emulator for debugging.

How do I build a non-debug .apk that I can just send around as a file anywhere that can install on devices? something about signatures I need to be aware of?

using Eclipse. And yes, feel free to post the obvious RTFM links (I'm working on several problems right now), but if there are any caveats or things I should watch out for then I would appreciate the insight!

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Eclipse: Right click the project, export, export android application. Follow the steps, including how to sign your app with a key you make in the wizard.